# Definition 2.3 in Lusztig's "Character Sheaves I"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, character-sheaves

About Definition 2.3 in [Character Sheaves I](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885900349): We have the usual $G$, $B$, $T$, Weyl group $W$ and roots $R$. Lusztig wrote down a definition of $R_{\mathcal{L}}$ as:
$$R_{\mathcal{L}}=\{\alpha\in R\;|\;r_{\alpha}\in W_{\mathcal{L}}'\}=\{\alpha\in R\;|\;\langle\alpha^{\vee},\lambda\rangle\equiv 0\;(\text{mod }n)\}$$
The question is: aren't these two different in general? I think only the right most one is correct, is it the case?

Here $r_{\alpha}\in W$ is the reflection associated to $\alpha\in R$, $\lambda\in\mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb{G}_m)$, $n$ some strictly positive integer, $\mathcal{L}=\lambda^*(\mathcal{E}_{n,\psi})$, $\mathcal{E}_{n,\psi}$ a character sheaf of order $n$ on $\mathbb{G}_m$ and $W_{\mathcal{L}}'=\{w\in W\;|\;w^*\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}\}=\{w\in W\;|\;w(\lambda)-\lambda\in n\cdot\mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb{G}_m)\}$.

After $R_{\mathcal{L}}$ one forms the Weyl group $W_{\mathcal{L}}$ with roots $R_{\mathcal{L}}$, and Lusztig performed the art of 2-sided cells on it. A lot of things thus depend on it. (I might be crazy, or just fail to find some erratum...)

Comment: Just to add that I found it's indeed the case that the rightmost definition is the correct one. Can't recall when is the first time it is used, but I think the papers do consistently use the rightmost one (if I am not crazy that the two definitions are different already for $G=SL(2)$).